How does dart event loop handle Streams?
Streams are meant to handle asynchronous flow of data which keeps on emitting data, but I want to understand how these streams are handled by event loop and where do they exist in main memory.
In a scenario where 2 StreamBuilders reacting upon 2 streams and parallel user interaction results in heavy activity in the flutter activity but how does event loop handle 2 streams along with user interaction altogether.
This scenario wants me to understand how do Streams really work with event loop and dart memory in dart vm
Can anyone explain me how dart handles one or multiple Streams at a time in the same event loop efficiently

A Stream is an object in memory. It can emit an event which results in associated listener callbacks being placed in the event queue.
Multiple streams emitting events simply result in more entries in the event queue, which are processed via the event loop one by one.
StreamBuilders are really just stream listeners that trigger sub-tree rebuilds.
